# Cannot seem to find the syntax to evaluate a trig expression

Tags: trigonometry

`3*Cos[t] == Cos[Sqrt[3]*t]` between the values `t=0` and `t=1`

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

```
eq = 3*Cos[t] == Cos[Sqrt[3]*t];
```

The equation is not satisfied in the interval `{0, 1}`. The root is approximately `1.91`

```
sol = Solve[{eq, 0 < t < Pi}, t]
```

[image]

where the solution is given as a [`Root`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Root.html) expression.

The approximate numeric value is

```
sol // N

(* {{t -> 1.90613}} *)
```

Verifying,

```
eq /. sol[[1]] // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```

Graphically,

```
Plot[Evaluate[List @@ eq], {t, 0, Pi},
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.7, .75}],
 Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[6],
   Point[{t, eq[[1]]} /. sol]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I did indeed make a mistake but, in case I had, I widened the parameters to 0-3. To no avail. I copied and pasted your syntax but I still get an error message: Solve::eqf: t<\[Pi] is not a well-formed equation. >> My version of Mathematica is rather old (7.01.0). Could that be the problem?

Comment: Try breaking the inequality into two segments: `eq = 3*Cos[t] == Cos[Sqrt[3]*t]; sol = Solve[{eq, 0 < t, t < Pi}, t]`. If that doesn't work, copy and paste your full code here.

Comment: In[25]:= eq15 = 3*Cos[t] == Cos[Sqrt[3]*t]; sol = 
 Solve[{eq15, 0 < t, t < Pi}, t]

During evaluation of In[25]:= Solve::eqf: t<\[Pi] is not a well-formed equation. >>

Out[25]= Solve[{3 Cos[t] == Cos[Sqrt[3] t], 0 < t, t < \[Pi]}, t]

Comment: Your code works fine here. Try restarting Mathematica and, if necessary, reboot your computer. Otherwise you may have to consider upgrading.